# Knockout.js Adding and Updating array in table

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am trying to create a table of employees using knockout.js. I have an array that is looped over for a table, and I have functions to edit and delete, but I want to create a text input box for adding Employees to the array, and in turn updating the table with the new employee's information. I have tried everything I know how to do, but since I am a beginner in knockout and javascript for that matter, I don't really know how to accomplish this.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="txtEmployee" class="col-2 col-form-label">Name: </label>
    <div class="col-6">
        <input type="text"
               data-bind="value: nameToAdd, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"
               class="form-control"
               id="txtName" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.add" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-dark table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>EmployeeId</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Functions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Employees">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            <td>
                <span>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: $root.edit">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"> </i> EDIT
                    </a>
                </span>
                |
                <span>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: $root.remove">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"> </i> DELETE
                    </a>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function Employee(id, name) {
     this.Id = id;
     this.Name = name;
};

var employeeList = [
     new Employee(1, "Justin"),
     new Employee(2, "John"),
     new Employee(3, "Sarah"),
     new Employee(4, "Tyler"),
     new Employee(5, "Mason")
];

function PayrollViewModel() {
     var self = this;
     self.nameToAdd = ko.observable("");
     self.Id = ko.observable("");
     self.Name = ko.observable("");

     var Employee = {
        Id: self.Id,
        Name: self.Name
     };

     self.Employee = ko.observable();
     self.Employees = ko.observableArray(employeeList);

     self.edit = function(Employee) {
        self.Employee(Employee);
     };

     self.remove = function(Employee) {
        self.Employees.remove(Employee);
     };

     self.cancel = function() {
        self.Employee(null);
     };

     self.update = function() {
        var l_employee = self.Employee();
        self.Employees.remove(self.Employee());
        self.Employees.push(l_employee);
     };

     self.add = function() {
        var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        this.Employees = [
           new Employee(random, nameToAdd)
        ]
        this.nameToAdd("");
     };
};

ko.applyBindings(new PayrollViewModel());
```

Answer (score 3):

There is more than one problem in your code. 
Number one is that `new Employee()` called from `PayrollViewModel.add()` will refer to `Employee` object which is defined inside the model (and not being a constructor) instead of `function Employee(id, name) {}` which you expect it to refer.

The second problem is that you are redefining `PayrollViewModel.Employees` on every call of `PayrollViewModel.add()`. This breaks knockout binding to the DOM - never redefine (rewrite) observables after bind, only assign em via `observable(newValue)` or using `.push()` method for observable arrays. So the right way to add new record in your case is `self.Employees.push(newItem)`.

See working example below:

```js
function Employee(id, name) {
 this.Id = id;
 this.Name = name;
};

var employeeList = [
 new Employee(1, "Justin"),
 new Employee(2, "John"),
 new Employee(3, "Sarah"),
 new Employee(4, "Tyler"),
 new Employee(5, "Mason")
];

function PayrollViewModel() {
 var self = this;
 self.nameToAdd = ko.observable("");
 self.Id = ko.observable("");
 self.Name = ko.observable("");

 self.Employee = ko.observable();
 self.Employees = ko.observableArray(employeeList);

 self.edit = function (Employee) {
  self.Employee(Employee);
 };

 self.remove = function (Employee) {
  self.Employees.remove(Employee);
 };

 self.cancel = function () {
  self.Employee(null);
 };

 self.update = function () {
  var l_employee = self.Employee();
  self.Employees.remove(self.Employee());
  self.Employees.push(l_employee);
 };

 self.add = function () {
  this.Employees.push({
   Id: self.Employees().length+1,
   Name: self.nameToAdd()
  });
  this.nameToAdd("");
 };
}

ko.applyBindings(new PayrollViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
 <label for="txtEmployee" class="col-2 col-form-label">Name: </label>
 <div class="col-6">
  <input type="text"
      data-bind="value:$root.nameToAdd,valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"
      class="form-control"
      id="txtName" />
 </div>
 <div class="col-4">
  <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.add" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
 </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-dark table-striped table-hover">
 <thead>
 <tr>
  <th>EmployeeId</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Functions</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: Employees">
 <tr>
  <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
  <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
  <td>
                <span>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: $root.edit">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"> </i> EDIT
                    </a>
                </span>
   |
   <span>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: $root.remove">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"> </i> DELETE
                    </a>
                </span>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Besides the above you problem with `edit` and `update` methods which are not bind to anything.

Comment: Thank you so much. I left out the html for the code and delete since I had that part working fine. Your solution was perfect. Thank you again.

Comment: @Friend0fMisery you are always welcome. btw, accepted answer is a nice way to say thank you on SA ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML changes**

I have changed your HTML slightly and have wrapped a form element around the input and submit elements. As you can see, the form element has the data-bind attached to the add() function. Hopefully this makes it a bit clearer where on submission of each input field which function will be fired.

**JavaScript**

I have created two view models, which is [one of the underlying concepts of Knockout.js.](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)

One view model is a config function that contains the users being created and another one which deals with adding the employees in the UI.

Ideally, the addEmployeeVM function should be a generic function that handles the removing, editing and adding but for learning purposes I have created to just add a user. You can change this to include the other methods.

I have not used the reference 'self' as many others do just because I think using a different term in each view model helps you identify what view model belongs to which one.

What I have done is extended the properties within **employeeConfigVM** so they can be accessed inside of **addEmployeeVM**. The idea is to try and continue building your application up like this, creating view models for different features/parts of your application, in different files so it is easy for you to scale up your app.

Look into [activating knockout](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#activating-knockout) to understand how to bind to different parts of your page, as you may only want to provide the functionality to a very small part and not to the rest of the page.

```js
var employeeConfigVM = function() {
  var empConfigVM = this;
  empConfigVM.employeeList = [
    new Employee(1, "Justin"),
    new Employee(2, "John"),
    new Employee(3, "Sarah"),
    new Employee(4, "Tyler"),
    new Employee(5, "Mason")
  ];

  function Employee(id, name) {
    this.Id = id;
    this.Name = name;
  };
}

var addEmployeeVM = function(id, userName) {
  var empVM = this;
  empVM.employeeConfig = new employeeConfigVM();
  empVM.Id = ko.observable("");
  empVM.Name = ko.observable("");
  empVM.Employee = ko.observable();
  empVM.Employees = ko.observableArray(empVM.employeeConfig.employeeList);

  empVM.add = function() {
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    empVM.Employees.push({
      Id: random,
      Name: empVM.Name()
    });
  };
};

var addUserVM = new addEmployeeVM();

$(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(addUserVM);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<form class="form-group row" data-bind="submit: add">
  <label for="txtEmployee" class="col-2 col-form-label">Name: </label>
  <div class="col-6">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.Name" class="form-control" id="txtName" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit">Add</button>
  </div>
</form>

<table class="table table-dark table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>EmployeeId</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Functions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.Employees">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
      <td>
        <span>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: $root.edit">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"> </i> EDIT
        </a>
      </span> |
        <span>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: $root.remove">
          <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"> </i> DELETE
        </a>
      </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```